# angular2 create an associative array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I would like to create an associative array in angular2 but havent found out a way yet

This is what i have tried

```
  onSubmit(){

let inputfield:any[]  = [];

for(var i=0; i<this.inspectionform.value["inputfileds"].length; i++){

 if(this.inspectionform.value["inputfileds"][i]["input"] != ""){
    //here i need help
    inputfield.push( i : this.inspectionform.value["inputfileds"][i]["input"]) //this returns a syntax error
  }

}
```

}
So what am actually looking forward to have is to pass a key and value to the array

Something like

```
1:sdbhd//pass this to the array
```

In the for loop i have tried

```
//inside the for loop

     let arrayval = [];
    arrayval.push(this.inspectionform.value["inputfileds"][i]["input"])
    arrayval.push(i)

    inputfield.push(arrayval);
```

This creates a new object every time of this nature

```
0:njnf
1:1(value of i)
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays - there's Objects and Arrays - you want an object (an un-ordered key/value pair)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Map, but I'd opt into a plain object;

**Demo**

```
const mything = {}
mything.foo = 1
mything.foo === mything['foo'] // true
mything['bar'] = 1337;
mything.bar === 1337 // true
mything.foo-bar = 1 // ERROR: can't have dashes
mything['foo-bar'] = 1 // Works
```

In ES6, or any relatively modern browser, you can get all the keys by using `Object.keys(mything)`. For older environments you're gonna have to loop over the keys using `for ... in` as demonstrated in this polyfill: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Another thing you have to be careful of is having the previous item defined in your property chain. For example if you have

```
var foobar = {
  foo: { bar: 1 }
}
```

then you **CAN** do `foobar.foo.bar.toString()` to get `"1"`, but if you try to do `foobar.foo.bang.toString()` you'll get an error cause `bang` is not defined on the `foo` object.

You can resolve this by doing a guard check like `foobar.foo.bang && foobar.foo.bang.toString()` which will only run the toString method if bang exists.

The easier way to do this would be to use `lodash` which gives you the `_.get`, and `_.set` which take care of the guards and the creation of the missing properties respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript does not have associate array, just use `{}` or new `Map` api

```
let xxxMap = new Map();

xxxMap.set('key1', 'value 1');

xxxMap.set('key2', 5);

console.log(xxxMap.get('key1'));
```

learn more from there: [Map in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: The problem now comes in the php backend when i check on the post request it shows the actual arrays but without the values set

Comment: i think the php backend shoud change the standard, in javascript, array could contain key, but you cannot count the length using `length` property.  `var s = []; s['in'] = 5; console.log(s['in']); console.log(s.length)` the return will: 5, 0.

Comment: could you provide some sample data send to server and response from server too

Comment: sample from server is : array(1) {
  [11]=>
  string(3) "dfd"
} , I would like to use both 11 and "dfd"